# Selective Scrolling in Excel

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, scrolling

I'm familiar with basic freeze pane functionality. However I'd like to scroll through a *specific* selection of cells.

I'd like for the first 7 rows to be frozen regardless of scrolling left or right on a table. IE, what's in the first 7 rows should always remain visible, no matter how I scroll the rest of the window. Is this possible?

Regular Freeze Panes won't work because I don't want the *header* (7 rows) to move. So when I scroll a table horizontally I want the header to move at all.

Below is an image that hopefully explains this better.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/191/jxz3.png/

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still can use freeze pane, except you now select only the header cells (and not the whole row).

Selecting the header **cells** will make it so that thew become frozen in both directions.

I'm doing some tests on Excel 2003 and it seems you need to select the outer cells that encompass the header in order for this to work.

EDIT: Found a working solution.

[image: Solution]

It isn't exactly what you asked, but it works as you want. The main points to notice are the following:

- The "Building Name" cell is merged, as such that the Logo and the important information is kept in the completely frozen upper left corner. This means that all other cells down this one need to be merged (dragging the "Building Name" cell downwards solves this)
- The upper right corner can only move sideways.
- The bottom left can only move up and down.

Comment: I've reread the question (I'm tired so, I'm prone to mistakes)... It might not be so linear as I say here, so, when I get the chance, I will post an example.

Comment: Thanks! This accomplishes half of what I need but I still can't scroll the network, layer 1, electrical, and hvac cells without scrolling the header as well.

Comment: The freeze pane functionality is quite limited in itself, so you can't do funky things with it. You can freeze the upper right corner and I think it's pretty much it.

Comment: I did something similar to that but my employer didn't like it. He's under the impression freeze panes works differently than it actually does. Thanks for the solution though. I'll be using it in the event I can't find a way to do it exactly how I want it. If that happens I'll mark this as the solution.

Comment: This remark is off-topic, but is this being printed? Printing these kinds of stuff does have a different workflow and there may be more ways to do things.

Comment: No, this isn't being printed.

Answer (score 0):

Excel can only freeze once in each direction, and unfortunately you cannot combine a split window and a freeze pane.  What you can do is click cell `E9` and freeze panes. This will freeze your header and your building information.

It won't freeze your yellow area, **BUT** you *could* put in a textbox or shape and modify its locked position in VBA so that it will "float".

Something like [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/floating-shapes-with-assigned-macros/40456cca-8e27-4a46-9e4f-397a3897f9d6) maybe.

I think that is sourced from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/Controls/5924.html).

Or, you could get real tricky like [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=55735&p=285829#post285829).

[image]